# org-structure-template Is Only Lowercase

Tags: org-mode, capitalization

When I type `<s`+`TAB`, a source code block is inserted, but the text is lowercase:

```
#+begin_src

#+end_src
```

How can I make it create uppercase text instead? I have always thought that uppercase was the standard.

I am using Doom Emacs, if that helps.

Comment: It looks like the block header/footer text is hard-coded in the function `org-tempo-add-block`, with no option to specify uppercase. The help file/info manual suggest they will be uppercase, but that's not possible with the existing code. Same with the new `org-insert-structure-template`, (`C-c, C-,`). This is surprising!

Comment: No, lower case is the (new) standard. The manuals use upper case to "to emphasize specific syntax in code snippets." See this [thread](https://orgmode.org/list/CADn3Z2KhELtaMpBz8obkUWsHDEtD2_T2jdLE-2ZuKoPKD3APyQ@mail.gmail.com/) on the ML.

Comment: @NickD Ha! There may be a reason behind this, but for users who haven't read that particular thread on the mailing list, it's still surprising (to me at least, and maybe also @lisp-machine) that the templates don't insert text that match the examples in the manual. This is arguably a documentation bug.

Comment: @Tyler: I'm not entirely convinced (one way or the other), but I (or you :-) ) might reply to that thread and point out the confusion (with this question as an example).

Comment: @Tyler thanks for pointing out that thread. I could find nothing in my initial web searches.